# Unable to read ISO-8859-1 files on a Wildfly 10 running on Linux?

Tags: java, linux, character-encoding, wildfly, iso-8859-1

I am running a wildfly 10.1.0 standalone server, and jdk version 1.8.0 update 161 (x64).

There is a problem occurring while reading ISO-8859-1 encoded files when wildfly is running on Linux.

Characters like `Ç` and `É` stay like `Ã?`. When the code runs on Windows, all characters stay fine.

I have verified and the file is indeed encoded as ISO-8859-1. Also, the code is enforcing the reading of the file as ISO-8859-1:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), "ISO-8859-1"));
```

I have tried iterating through all the available charsets, but had no good results:

```
Charset.availableCharsets().keySet().stream().forEach( cs -> {
    try {
        Charset charset = Charset.forName(cs);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = Files.newBufferedReader(importFile.toPath() , charset );
        File out = new File(outDir + cs + ".txt");
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = Files.newBufferedWriter(out.toPath(), charset , StandardOpenOption.CREATE);
        String ln = null;
        bufferedWriter.write(cs+"\n");
        while ( (ln = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null ) {
            bufferedWriter.write(ln + "\n");
            System.out.println(ln);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
} );
```

As expected, it is not a problem with the operating system itself, because if I run a simple java program, outside the application server, that reads the same file and writes its content, it goes perfectly well.

Can someone help me? I have tested on a Ubuntu 18.04, with UTF-8 as the default system encoding.

Comment: Try to print  System.getProperty("file.encoding")) at the beginning of your program. The default charset (on OS-level) might be different. If so, force it using: java -Dfile.encoding= ISO-8859-1.

Comment: Yes, it prints differently for each OS, but even forcing it, just like you said, does not change anything.